# How to name tables and columns ? SQL

Tags: sql

I wondered what was the best way to name columns and tables in SQL ?

Currently, my tables are named like that : "users" and the columns "user_id, user_password". I know prefixing the columns with the table name is a bad idea and this iw why I came to ask my question.

What's the best way ?

Comment: Use names like : John. Peter, MAry etc

Comment: Hum... that's a possibility, yes... x)

Comment: You cannot just drop the table_ prefix. Then, you are in trouble indeed. The coulmn naming defenitely affects the table name.

Comment: I don't really understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ISO-11179 Naming Conventions](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/iso-11179-naming-conventions) 
What you want is  11179-5, part 5: Naming and Identification Principles

> This part of ISO/IEC 11179 provides guidance for the identification of
>   administered items. Identification is a broad term for designating, or
>   identifying, a particular data item. Identification can be
>   accomplished in various ways, depending upon the use of the
>   identifier. Identification includes the assignment of numerical
>   identifiers that have no inherent meanings to humans; icons (graphic
>   symbols to which meaning has been assigned); and names with embedded
>   meaning, usually for human understanding, that are associated with the
>   data item's definition and value domain.